# Upgrade QGIS from 1.8 Lisboa to 2.0?

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-2

I have QGIS 1.8 and I want to upgrade to 2.0 Dufour...

Should I just download the file and launch the installation, or first uninstall 1.8?

Comment: you can run them both on the same PC.

Comment: But... I suppose I won't need both after... so I have to uninstall 1.8?

Comment: Before you do that, I would suggest you check and make sure all / any of the plugins you use in 1.8 have been created for 2.0.  There is a difference between the plugins for 1.8 and 2.0.  Plugins developed for 1.8 will not work in 2.0; you will need to either have the plugins changed to the 2.0 style, or use 1.8 on specific tasks.

Comment: what operating system are you using. In windows you can keep both.

Answer (score 2):

4 Versions of QGIS on 1 PC running Windows 7 64bit (Intel core i7)

[image]

**Some 1.9.0 Plugins not compatible with 2.0.1

Comment: An overachiever in our midst!

Comment: not including the virtualbox Ubuntu verison...

Comment: Only one virtual box? I have got several linux flavours running in different virtual boxes. I dropped 1.9.0, but have 2.1.0 installed as well.